# Divisibility rules with prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ with the property that
$$
7 \mid\left(n^{3}+1\right)
$$
but $7$ does not divide $\left(n^{2}-2 n-3\right) .$ Prove that $7 \mid(4 n+1)$.

So far I got:

$n^3+1 = (n+1)\cdot(n^2-n+1)$, since $7$ is a prime, so
$7\mid(n+1)$ or $7\mid(n^2-n+1)$.

And since $7$ does not divide $\left(n^{2}-2 n-3\right) = (n-3)\cdot(n+1)$, I know that $7\mid(n^2-n+1)$.

And $7$ does not divide the difference of $(n^2-n+1)$ and $(n^2-2n-3)$ which is $n+4$.

Same since $7$ is prime, $7$ does not divide $4n+16\Rightarrow$$7$ does not divide $4n+2$.

Then I am stuck here, how could I use the information I got so far to prove $7 \mid(4 n+1)$?

Really hope someone could help/hint me with it! Thank you!

Comment: Step 1: Assume that $n \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, and **manually** explore the consequences of this assumption.

Comment: Do you know basic modular arithmetic? For what $n=0,1,\dots,6$ is $n^3+1\equiv 0 \pmod 7$?

Comment: Show for all $n$
$$7\mid (n+1)(n+2)(n+4)-(n^3+1)$$ and $$7\mid (n+1)(n+4)-(n^2-2n-3)$$

Comment: Hint: prime $\,p\nmid a\Rightarrow p\mid b \iff p\mid a\ {\rm or}\ p\mid b\iff p\mid ab\ \ $

Answer (score 4):

Two methods:

*Method 1*

If $n^3\equiv-1\bmod 7$ then $n\in\{3,5,6\}\bmod 7$. But $n\in\{3,6\}$ renders $n^2-2n-3=(n+1)(n-3)\equiv0$, denied by hypothesis, and the last possibility $n\equiv5$ renders $4n+1\equiv0$.

*Method 2*

Multiply $n^2-2n-3$ by $4n+1$:

$(n^2-2n-3)(4n+1)=4n^3-7n^2-14n-3\equiv4(n^3+1)\bmod 7$

Thus if the prime number $7$ divides $n^3+1$ it must divide (at least) one of the factors $n^2-2n-3$ or $4n+1$.

Answer (score 2):

Further factor $n^2 - n + 1 \equiv (n - 3)(n - 5) \mod 7$. Since $n - 3 \neq 0 \mod 7$, we see that $n - 5 \equiv 0 \mod 7$. So $n \equiv 5 \mod 7$. So $4n + 1 \equiv 0 \mod 7$.

Comment: Wow, it's such succinct proof! And thank you so much! I am wondering how did you get the $(n-3)(n-5)$ part from $n^2-n+1$? Is it by intuition or?

Comment: @JesseJin Given that we know that $n - 3 \neq 0 \mod 7$, I highly suspected that fact would play directly into the proof. My initial thought was to try $(n^2 - 2n - 3) \cdot (4n + 1)$, but that didn't work. Then, I realised that $4n + 1 \equiv 4(n - 5) \mod 7$ and tried computing $(n^2 - 2n - 3)(n - 5)$, which did work.

Comment: $(n^2-2n-3)(4n+1)=4n^3-7n^2-14n-3\equiv4(n^3+1)\bmod7$. What could have gone wrong with that product?

Comment: @OscarLanzi I immediately abandoned the effort because I saw the leading coefficient would be $4$ and thus the result would not be exactly $n^3 + 1$. But now I see that if I had looked a bit further ahead, I could have solved the problem even faster. Your method seems even better than mine.

Comment: @JesseJin In my answer I explain more generally the key idea used (implicitly) above.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done more generally and *algorithmically* by a gcd as in the Lemma below.  Here $\,b = n^2\!-\!2n\!-\!3\,$ is coprime to $\,c=7\,$ so we can cancel out out any common factors $\,b\,$ has with $\, a = n^3+1\,$ without affecting divisibility of $\,a\,$ by $7.\,$ Computing the gcd $\!\bmod 7\,$ by the Euclidean algorithm we get $\, (a,b) = b,\,$ so  $\,7\mid a \iff 7\mid a/b \equiv n+2\iff n\equiv -2\,$ $\,(\Rightarrow 4n+1\equiv 0)$.

**Lemma** $\ $ If $\,(b,c) = 1\,$ then $\,c\mid a\iff c\mid a/(a,b)$

**Proof** $\ $ Since $\,b\,$ is coprime to $c$ it is also coprime to its factor $\,d=(a,b),\,$ so by Euclid's Lemma $\,c\mid a = da/d\iff c\mid a/d$